# CFRunLoopAddSource: Run Mode to execute immediately

Tags: macos, cocoa, accessibility-api

I'm trying to add an observer to the active window (could be any program, not just mine) so that it tells me if it's **moving**. Here's how I added the observer to the run loop:

```
AXObserverAddNotification(m_observer, (AXUIElementRef)activeWindow, kAXMovedNotification, (__bridge void*)self);
CFRunLoopAddSource( [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] getCFRunLoop], AXObserverGetRunLoopSource(m_observer),kCFRunLoopDefaultMode );
```

The callback that is associated to the observer currently just prints something to the output window. What I observe is that nothing is output when I'm dragging around the active window (again, this could be **any** app's window) but as soon as I stop, multiples of the printf results are output. Seems like the calls to the callback are queued until there's some idle time for it to execute all at once.

Is there a way to get the callback executed without waiting for idle time? Maybe a CFRunLoopMode that would do that?